# R Counting the element of a cell

Tags: r, counting

I can' t find an answer to this, maybe I haven't  asked properly

I have to count the occurrences in every cells of a column (Year) in R.

```
Year  
c(2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)
c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015)
c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2017)
```

I need to have a column aside in which are indicated the number of years included in column Year

```
Year  
c(2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)
c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015)
c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2017)

Count
11
11
12
```

Comment: *I have to count the occurrences in every cells of a column in R*...so you have a data frame? You are probably looking for `length()`

Comment: Can you add data using `dput` ? `dput(df)` ?